# Two-way lookup function

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a matrix of values with column headers (ID numbers) up top, and Item numbers down the rows. I want to do a lookup by (ID number, Item number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula:

```
=INDEX(B2:D4,MATCH(B6,A2:A4,0),MATCH(B7,B1:D1,0))
```

Works on B8 of this example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A very common method is to use INDEX with two MATCH functions as described [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html#IndexMatch3)

INDEX is usually preferable to OFFSET because it isn't volatile (i.e. it doesn't re-calculate evry time the worksheet calculates like OFFSET)

Comment: I agree. I usually don't care about volatile functions when they appear only once, but using them when there is a better alternative is not good practice. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To look in area A1 > E6
G1 is row number, H1 is column number

```
=VLOOKUP(G1; $A$1:$E$6; MATCH(H1; $A$1:$E$1; 0); FALSE)
```

or commas "**,**" instead of semicolons "**;**"